# WPF: RadGridView set template for some cells

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, grid, radgridview

I have a grid like this:

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="DataG"
 ItemsSource="{Binding CamposUsu}"
 SelectedItem="{Binding Selected}"
 CanUserReorderColumns="True"
 CanUserResizeColumns="True"
 CanUserSortColumns="False"
 SelectionUnity="FullRow"
 IsReadyOnly="True"
 AutoGenerateColumns="False"
 Loaded="DataG_Loaded" />
```

In the .cs file the method DataG_Loaded:

```
private void DataG_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventesArgs e)
{
   DataTemplate labelTemplate = new DataTemplate();

            FrameworkElementFactory label = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Label));
            label.SetValue(Label.ContentProperty, "Unlimited");

            labelTemplate.VisualTree = label;

            labelTemplate.Seal();

            this.DataG.Columns[7].CellTemplate = labelTemplate; 
            //this column 7 is a column called "Vl." with double values
}
```

Well, when I comment the method DataG_Loaded, my grid is fulfilled correctly with the objects I created on my viewmodel.
When I uncomment the method, the column "Vl." that had values like "93.5", "108.9"... is all fulfilled with the value "Unlimited".

This was already expected.
I want only the cells that the value is > 100.0 to turn to the string "Unlimited". For example:

[image: Example]

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a value converter on your data binding for that column in the XAML instead of using the Loaded event of your grid.

### Example

Create a new class that inherits [IValueConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) like this:

```
public class UnlimitedNumberConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
       if (((float)value) > 100)
           return "Unlimited";

        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
    }
}
```

Add a resource to your XAML in order to access the converter:

```
<converters:UnlimitedNumberConverter x:Key="UnlimitedNumberConverter"/>
```

where "converters" is a namespace alias declared at the top of your XAML window/user control:

```
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MyApplication.Converters"
```

Then reference the converter in your data binding on the grid through XAML:

```
{Binding VI_Value, Converter={StaticResource UnlimitedNumberConverter}}
```

Comment: @Evil Str, please let me know if this helped you or if you still need assistance. Thanks!